# fill sequence of datetimes

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, posixct, seq

I have a data.frame consisting of IDs, DateTimes and Values. For each ID I want to expand the DateTimes so that there is one every hour between the min and max. The ID and Value columns should be filled with their respective values (i.e. not NA). There will never be case where there are multiple unique Value values for each ID. For example the new data.frame should have 4 rows with ID == 1 and 5 rows with ID == 2 (9 rows total). What is simplest way to do this?

I commonly work with dplyr so will accept both base or dplyr/tidyverse methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt <- Sys.time() %>% floor_date('hours')
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
                 DateTime = c(dt, dt + hours(3), dt + hours(6), dt + hours(9)),
                 Value = c(3, 3, 4, 4))
```

the expected output is:

```
output <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                     DateTime = c(dt, dt + hours(1), dt + hours(2), dt + hours(3), 
                                  dt + hours(6), dt + hours(7), dt + hours(8), dt + hours(9)),
                     Value = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4))

  ID            DateTime Value
1  1 2018-03-27 19:00:00     3
2  1 2018-03-27 20:00:00     3
3  1 2018-03-27 21:00:00     3
4  1 2018-03-27 22:00:00     3
5  2 2018-03-28 01:00:00     4
6  2 2018-03-28 02:00:00     4
7  2 2018-03-28 03:00:00     4
8  2 2018-03-28 04:00:00     4
```

Comment: I've modified the original data.frame slightly and provided expected output

Comment: My output differs from yours as the time zone is different

Comment: yes output differs that is not a problem. I just need the Value column to be filled as well as ID

Comment: If the Value column is the same for each ID, just use `group_by(ID, Value)`

Comment: perfect thanks. That's nice simple solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID, Value) %>% 
   complete(DateTime = seq(min(DateTime), max(DateTime), by = "1 hour")) %>%
   select(names(df))
```

Comment: almost. This solution does not 'complete' the Value column as well

Comment: @sebdalgarno  In your example, the Value column is the same for each 'ID'  IS that the case.  So, I used `fill`